# Does SnakeYAML not unescape escaped strings?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm attempting to replace use of an older YAML parser/formatter with SnakeYAML, but when I try to test an escaped string, it doesn't seem to unescape it.

Code:

```
new Yaml().load("Name: \"\\xe3\\x83\\x86\\xe3\\x82\\xb9\\xe3\\x83\\x88\"\n");
```

Result:

- result = {java.util.LinkedHashMap@1876}  size = 1

  - "Name" -> "ãã¹ã"

I expected the library to take care of unescaping this for me, so it should have resulted in "テスト" for the name. Am I missing something obvious? I can't see any way to get custom settings in here for how to treat strings that doesn't involve replacing entire implementations of construction code.

Comment: This looks like an encoding issue, not an escaping issue.

Comment: @JordanRunning it's somewhere on the line between the two... it's like it unescaped it but has assumed that each `\x` is an individual character, whereas the previous parser took `\x` to mean an escaped byte, and dealt with the UTF-8 sequences.